# testcafe electron mainWindowUrl | what to do with tmp location

Tags: testing, electron, automated-tests, testcafe, e2e

When using testcafe-browser-provider-electron, I get stuck with the mainWindowUrl. I have the original source file in the renderer folder, the version that is in the build folder and apparently a temporary created in some random /tmp/ folder. Testcafe suggests the /tmp/ file.

"Use the mainWindowUrl option to specify one of the following pages as the main window page:
file:///tmp/.mount_PROGRAM-Lbt5yL/resources/app.asar/build/renderer/index.html"

With the 6 chars being random.
How can I instruct testcafe that all files are identical?

I expected no error-message
Error: The main window page at file://....index.html was not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this behavior. Please track the issue in the following thread: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron/issues/87. We will research it and update the thread once we have any news.

Answer (score 0):

Found out an alternative path to using the AppImage.

Use electron-builder to build a deb-package. Install that as it will always have the same path /opt/... to the unpacked content. You can then use that path in the specification of the mainWindowUrl.